How to repair crack in gaming chair arm
I have had a gaming chair for about 5 years now and there is this crack in the arm that has been bothering me for a while. Is there a way to repair this? Should I bother repairing it?enter image description here


Or just buy covers for the arm rests

Highlighting the crack would make the picture more useful. Need some good zooming to find it. The crack is on the left arm rest, on the right side of the rest, in the middle.

The material of the arm rest is important on how to fix/repair it.  I guess it is vinyl like, and there are vinyl repairs kits on the market.

I had one of these, but got rid of it because it wasn't that comfortable.  So I can't lay eyes on the parts—but have you looked into replacement parts for this chair?

the area of interest takes up less that 0.1% of the image ... please post a picture where the crack fills more than 50% of the picture

That is cosmetic, not functional.
Fill it up with proper mastic, plastic putty or even with just silicone.

A non structural fix may let it pull loose and continue to tear further, but we'll certainly restore function. Question: do you actually use the armrests? Not everyone does, and if not the simplest long-term fix is to dismount them.

@keshlam I do use them.

Purchase a pair of office chair arm rest covers. Then if any other cracking occurs it will be covered as well.
